# Where does `podman network create` store networks, and is it compatible with /etc/cni/net.d?

Tags: podman

I used `podman network create` to make a network. Is that information persisted in a database and not in individual files in e.g. `/etc/cni/net.d`? podman is using netavark, on Fedora Server 37.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to `/usr/share/containers/containers.conf` on Fedora CoreOS

```
# Path to the directory where network configuration files are located.
# For the CNI backend the default is "/etc/cni/net.d" as root
# and "$HOME/.config/cni/net.d" as rootless.
# For the netavark backend "/etc/containers/networks" is used as root
# and "$graphroot/networks" as rootless.
```